# Error catching close in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to catch the close of my form so that when a user exits, it saves "User has exited" to a text file, this is my code:

```
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
        {
            Close();
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
        else
        {
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");

            TextWriter msg = new StreamWriter(directory, true);

            msg.WriteLine(" (" + time + ") == " + uName + " Has Left The Chat == ");

            msg.Close();

            Close();
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
   }
```

My problem is, I get this error:

> "Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion"

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Well Close will raise the `formClosing` event so you are calling it again here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot call the Close() method from form closing. Remove all the Close() calls and it will work.

```
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
    {
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");

        using(TextWriter msg = new StreamWriter(directory, true))
        { 
            msg.WriteLine(" (" + time + ") == " + uName + " Has Left The Chat == ");
            msg.Close();
        }
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: im trying, it says i have to wait 10 minutes, for spam i guess, when thats up, i'll mark it, and thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to be calling the `Close()` method. Someone already called it, if the `mainForm_FormClosing` event was executed.

Answer (score 2):

The event "**mainForm_FormClosing**" is executing due to Form has been closed, no need to call **"Close();"** in If and Else condition.

If you do so you will get an "System.StackOverflowException"